# Apache ProxyPass by dynamic hostname

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure Apache to proxy to an internal server based on dynamic hostnames and using other ports. It seems to be a little bit too complicated for me.
This is what I have:

```
<Location /awesomewebapp>
ProxyPass http://[internalservername]:8080/awesomewebapp
ProxyPassReverse http://[internalservername]:8080/awesomewebapp
</Location>
```

But this is (obviously) not dynamic. I have been working on rewrite rules etc. but I failed to make it work. What I really need is something like:

```
^/[internalservername]/awesomewebapp
      proxy internally to
http://[internalservername]:8080/awesomewebapp
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous "solution" was still not working properly so I deleted it to prevent confusion. It seems not to be possible the way I want it, but a small workaround using a subdomain instead of subdirectory still makes it rock.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%1:8080/$1 [P]
```

Source: http://www.vanbommelonline.nl/2011/10/using-apache-for-dynamic-reverse-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use RewriteRule to proxy a request.  The [apache documentation for using mod_rewrite as a proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html) shows the following:

> Description:
>
> mod_rewrite provides the [P] flag, which allows URLs to be passed, via mod_proxy, to another server. Two examples are given here. In one example, a URL is passed directly to another server, and served as though it were a local URL. In the other example, we proxy missing content to a back-end server.
>
> Solution:
>
> To simply map a URL to another server, we use the [P] flag, as follows:
>
> RewriteEngine  on
>   RewriteBase    "/products/"
>   RewriteRule    "^widget/(.*)$"  "http://product.example.com/widget/$1"  [P]
>      ProxyPassReverse "/products/widget/" "http://product.example.com/widget/"
>
> In the second example, we proxy the request only if we can't find the resource locally. This can be very useful when you're migrating from one server to another, and you're not sure if all the content has been migrated yet.
>
> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
>      RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-d
>     RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://old.example.com/$1" [P]
>     ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://old.example.com/"

The second example, conditionally rewriting URLs with the [P] flag to proxy the request seems like what you need.

Comment: Worked with this, but it looks like ProxyPassReverse removes the host from the url. Now the full URL "http://[publicdomain]/[internalhostname]/awesomewebapp" redirects to "http://[internalhostname]/awesomewebapp" correctly, but then it returns publicly as "http://[publicdomain]/awesomewebapp" without the internal hostname in the path.